# For a linear regression of Y on X, when is the regression of X on Y linear? When is it non-linear?

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ that both have finite expectations, that may or may not be correlated, and that are *known* to be linearly related (i.e., I mean their sum forms a straight line of constant slope) according to the equation,
$$
Y = aX_1 + bX_2 .
$$
We know, by construction, that $E[Y|X_1=x_1]$ is is a straight line with constant slope. Then, when is $E[X_1|Y=y]$ also linear in the same sense?

Based on  simulations, I believe that $E[X_1|Y=y]$ will be a straight line with constant slope if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., but I can't find a proof. It is certainly linear when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both independent Normal.

One simple example of when $E[X_1|Y=y]$ is not linear (does not have constant slope) is when $X_1\sim Uniform[-c_1,c_1]$ and $X_2\sim Uniform[-c_2,c_2]$ when $c_1\neq c_2$. In this case, $E[X_1|Y=y]$ has a zigzag shape, increasing initially for small y then flattening out at zero for a while then increasing again.

So, is there a proof that $E[X_1|Y=y]$ is a straight line with constant slope for i.i.d. $X_1$ and $X_2$, and are there instances when $E[X_1|Y=y]$ is linear but $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not i.i.d.?

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Here are examples below demonstrating a case when $E[X_1|Y=y]$ is not linear (i.e., does not form a straight line with constant slope despite $E[Y|X_1]$ being linear), specifically with $X_1 \sim Uniform[-2,2]$ and $X_2 \sim Uniform[-3,3]$ and coefficients a = b = 1. The first two plots are simulated data, where the black line is a moving average. The third plot is the actual numerical solution found by computing the conditional pdf and integrating.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is clear, but your terminology might confuse readers. Your initial definition of "linearly related" is without content: *all* pairs of random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ enjoy such a relation.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257779 for a somewhat related question.  For insight into all three of your questions, think of $X_1$ as an "independent variable," $bX_2$ as an "error term," and draw pictures.

Comment: @whuber I am indeed thinking of bX2 as an error term. I am trying to figure out how to post images so that I can post images of the numerical and simulation output to demonstrate what I mean . . .

Comment: @whuber ok, figures added. How should I phrase the linearity part to make it more accurate?

Comment: The linear relation to which you refer is between $X_1$ and $Y,$ not between $X_1$ and $X_2.$  If you were to plot the curve $y=ax_1$ on $(x_1,y)$ axes, then adding $bX_2$ will alter the heights of that graph randomly according to the distribution of $X_2.$ Since you allow $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be correlated (you don't even require the mean of $X_2$ conditional on $X_1$ be zero), those alterations may follow literally any path--even a deterministic one.  Drawing a few such plots will reveal why the regression of $X_1$ against $Y$ can be almost arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: @whuber yes, I agree that the regression of $X_1$ on $Y$ can be almost arbitrarily complicated. Thus my question: when is $E[X_1|Y=y]$ a straight line? It is a straight line when  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid Normal. What other conditions? Is iid $X_1$ and $X_2$ also sufficient?

Comment: A slight modification of your own example shows *iid* does not suffice.

Comment: @whuber what is that modification? Every distribution I've tried (e.g., Exponential, Uniform, Gamma, even Cauchy!) gives a straight line for $E[X_1|Y=y]$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid. When the limits of the uniform distributions are the same (e.g., if you change $X_2 \sim Unifrom[-2,2]$ in my example) $E[X_1|Y=y]$ is a straight line.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out an answer that I'll leave here in case anyone else has the same question. As a non-math person I could use some help making this more precise, and I would still like to have a citation for this theorem, since this must be a well known result.

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid and $Y = X_1+X_2$, then $E[X_1|Y=y]$ must be a straight line with slope 1/2.

Proof: Solving for $X_1$ and taking the conditional expectation gives
$$
E[X_1|Y=y]=y-E[X_2|Y=y]
$$
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, then $E[X_1|Y=y]=E[X_2|Y=y]=y/2$, which is a straight line with constant slope equal to 1/2.

Comment: +1. The relevant concept is *exchangeability,* implied by the *iid* assumption.  Because of that and linearity of conditional expectation, $$y = E[Y\mid Y=y] = E[X_1+X_2\mid X_1+X_2=y] = E[X_1\mid X_1+X_2=y] + E[X_2\mid X_1+X_2=y].$$ Since the two terms are equal (by exchangeability), each must equal $y/2,$ *QED.*

Comment: @whuber Thanks!