# Is the least mean square estimator for jointly gaussian variables necessarily affine?

Tags: regression, unbiased-estimator

In his book on adaptive filtering, [Sayed](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=VBaenqIVftUC&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=%22There%20is%20an%20important%20special%20case%20for%20which%20the%20optimal%20estimator%20of%20Thm.%201.1%20turns%20out%20to%20be%20affine%20in%20y%22&source=bl&ots=gmNByk7KE1&sig=ACfU3U1CKDCyHXsb65uAQj4aLbZd8PwEFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX2-_O5If3AhWvjJUCHTZ5DUQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22There%20is%20an%20important%20special%20case%20for%20which%20the%20optimal%20estimator%20of%20Thm.%201.1%20turns%20out%20to%20be%20affine%20in%20y%22&f=false) mentions a subclass of affine estimators in which not only the predictions *y* are linearly dependent on the observations *x*, but *x* and *y* are jointly Gaussian. From that, I wonder: in case two random variables are jointly Gaussian, then the optimal estimator E(y|x) (the so-called "least mean square estimator") is necessarily affine? If yes, are there any cases where two random variables are linearly related but are not jointly Gaussian?

Comment: With respect to your last question, there are infinitely many:  $y = 2x + e$, where $x \sim U(0,1)$ and $e \sim U(-1,1)$, for example.

Comment: Your second question is answered with an explicit example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257779/is-there-a-parametric-joint-distribution-such-that-x-and-y-are-both-uniform/258389#258389.  Your first one is answered by examining any formula you like for the least squares solution.