# Multivariate Probability Distribution with Linear Conditional Expectation

Tags: linear, conditional-expectation, multivariate-distribution

I want to know what probability distribution has the linearity property of the conditional expectation.

To be specific, suppose that we have three random variables named $v_1,\;v_2,\;v_3$.

Then, if $[v_1,\;v_2,\;v_3]$ follows a joint normal distribution, we can show that $\mathbb{E}[v_1|v_2,\;v_3]$ is linear in $v_2$ and $v_3$.

That is, $\mathbb{E}[v_1|v_2,\;v_3]=\rho'[v_2,\;v_3]'$, where $\rho$ is a $2\times1$ constant vector consists of covariance of $[v_1,\;v_2,\;v_3]$.

Here, according to a textbook, there are diverse probability distributions that have the same linearity of the conditional expectation.

But, I am not sure what distributions also have that property.

Could you give me some examples (with proof if possible).

Comment: There is a *huge* number of such distributions one can construct.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257779 for an example.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment every time. Your answers make me inspired and are always informative :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multivariate Elliptical distributions deals with linearity in conditional expectation. You can think about this family as a generalization of Normal distribution,  t-Student is another notable example of this family.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that jointly continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf with constant value $2$ on the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,1), (0,1)$ in the plane. Note that this is the joint pdf of $X = \min(U,V)$ and $Y=\max(U,V))$ where $U$ and $V$ are i.i.d, $\mathcal U(0,1)$ random variables. Then, $E[X\mid Y] = \frac 12 Y$ and $E[Y\mid X] = \frac 12 + \frac 12 X$ both are linear functions of $Y$ and $X$ respectively.

As to whether the joint distribution of the minimum and maximum of two independent $\mathcal U(0,1)$ random variables is "a typical well-known distribution" or not is something that I leave for the *cognoscenti* on this group to decide. I am just an engineer and a mere dabbler in statistics, not a statistician

Comment: So, your point is that the linearity could hold even though the joint distribution is not a typically well-known one. Right?

Comment: @M.C.Park You asked "Could you give me some examples (with proof if possible)?" and so I gave you an example.  I didn't _prove_ that $E[X\mid Y]$ and $E[Y\mid X]$ are linear functions as you want, but then, neither did the answer that you have accepted.

Comment: I doubt I count among any *cognoscenti*, but for what it's worth I'd call that distribution "well-known" (and the claimed property is so starkly obvious in this case that it is a perfect example to give).

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think, I made a misleading point in my question by using the term "example". That is, the word "example" is ambiguous in the question. What I mean by "example" was "a family of distributions" such as normal, logistic, and so on. That is the reason why I accepted the first answer. I am sorry for my use of the vague term.

Comment: @Glen_b Your false modesty cuts no ice with me or with any other readers of this forum for that matter!.  Your opinions and kind words are most valued.

Comment: @M.C.Park but in this case you're necessarily dealing with bivariate distributions but your named "families" seem to be mentioning only marginal distributions. There are many bivariate distributions with logistic margins or normal margins. Dilip's example is one with triangular margins.