# How to create uniformly sampled timeseries ($\mathcal{R}^{n \times t}$) that has a specified correlation matrix, $C \in \mathcal{R} ^{n \times n}$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, sampling

Is this possible to do numerically?  I know we can sample timeseries from Gaussian (or other) distributions that have a specified correlation structure.  But can it be done for Uniform?

Comment: Related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/generate-pairs-of-random-numbers-uniformly-distributed-and-correlated . Seems like your answer will depend on using copulas. The question is for bivariate, but the code provided in top answer works for larger dimensions.